# Get clicked element in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have HTML in the following format:

```
<div class="panel panel-1 active" data-chart="flight-chart">
   <div class="row panel-header">
      <div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-plane fa-4x"></i></div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
         <div class="big">123,673</div>
         <div class="small">flights added since 3/3/2016</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-footer">view more information</div>
</div>
```

I am capturing click events using the code below:

```
Template.infoPanel.events
  'click .panel': (event, instance) ->
    console.log 'panel click',event.target
```

The issue I am having is that depending on where in the `.panel` div I click, a different element is returned for `event.target`.  So If I click on the `.col-sm-9` div, that will be returned as the target even though the event is targeting it's parent `.panel`.  Same goes for clicking on `.panel-footer`.

How can I get the `.panel` element 100% of the time from inside of the click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `currentTarget` instead:

```
console.log 'panel click', event.currentTarget
```

See the [Event Maps](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps) section of the docs for more details.